# How to create a database block under toggle block via Notion api?

Tags: database, toggle, block, notion-api, notion

I just want to create a database block under toggle block as below via Notion API or notion sdk.

1. The first solution I pop up is creating a toggle block first. Then I use POST or PATCH /block api to add the child_*database under toggle's children. However, the /block api didn't support child*_database property.
2. Another solution  I tried is create a toggle block first. Then creating another database separately via POST /database, assigned the parent to the block. However the /database only support parent info , page and database. I can not assign it to block.

   Expected Result
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYsaV.png)